# CSS !important not taking precedence in Semantic UI

Tags: jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I'm working on a header. It looks like this:

```
<nav class="ui fixed borderless menu huge">
    <div class="ui container grid">
      <!-- regular navbar -->
      <div class="computer only row">
        <!-- left menu -->
        <a href="#" class="header item" id="logo-header">
          TMP
        </a>
        <a href="" class="item">Home</a>

        <a href="" class="item">Others</a>

        <!-- right menu -->
        <div class="right menu">
          <div class="item">
            <i class="search icon"></i>
          </div>
          <a href="" class="ui dropdown item">
            <div class="cart-menu">
              <i class="black large cart icon"></i>
              <div class="floating ui red label cart-items-badge">5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="menu">
              <!-- cart items -->
            </div>
          </a>
          <a href="" class="item">Login/Register</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- mobile navbar -->
      <div class="mobile-navbar tablet mobile only row">
        <a href="#" class="header item">
          <img class="store-logo" src="./img/vnl_logo.png" />
          <span class="store-title">TMP</span>
        </a>
        <div class="right menu">
          <div class="item mobile-search-icon">
            <div class="ui fluid transparent left icon input">
              <!-- <i class="search icon"></i> -->
              <input type="text" id="mobile-search-box" placeholder="Search...">
              <label for="mobile-search-box">
                <span><i class="search icon"></i></span>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="menu item toggle burger">
            <span class="ui basic icon">
              <i class="content icon"></i>
            </span>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="ui vertical borderless fluid menu">
          <a href="#" class="item">Home</a>
          <a href="#" class="item">Categories</a>
          <a href="#" class="item">
            Cart
            <div class="floating ui red label">5</div>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="item">About</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

On mobile, when the Search icon is clicked on, I want it to be expanded across the header, leaving this distribution:

LOGO - Search Bar - Menu Burger

Where Search Bar takes 80% of the whole width. To do so, I'm doing the following:

Js:

```
$('.mobile-search-icon').click(expandSearchMobile)

function expandSearchMobile(e) {
  $('div.mobile-navbar .store-title').css('display', 'none')
  $('div.mobile-navbar .right.menu').addClass('search-on')
  $('div.mobile-navbar .right.menu .mobile-search-icon').css("width", "100%")
}
```

css:

```
.mobile-navbar div.right.menu.search-on {
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
    -webkit-transition: width 1.6s;
  transition: width 1.6s;
  transition: width 1.6s;
  transition: width 1.6s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

But the burger is disappearing, well, not exactly, is being pushed to the right. That's why in my css I'm setting the margin left to be 0. This property is originally being set by the framework:

```
.ui.menu:not(.vertical) .right.item, .ui.menu:not(.vertical) .right.menu {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    margin-left: auto!important;
```

But my !important is not taking precedence over the margin-left defined in the framework.

I do not want to go and remove the !important from the framework, modifying the framework is not an option for me.

Any other approach that I can use?

Here's a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/La11m48f/

Thanks.

Comment: Create a demo that reproduces the issue

Comment: Do you load the framework's CSS after your custom CSS? if so, try loading your CSS last... Last CSS rule is the one applied. And care about the `@media` ones...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette no, I load first framework's CSS and at the very end my custom CSS files

Comment: Is your JS writing any CSS? If it is the !important CSS will likely be ignored as JS (JQuery) writes the CSS in the HTML ex: <h1 style="width:100%;"></h1> Note this is only relevant where the styles conflict.

Comment: @charlietfl I just added a link to a fiddle in the question. Thx

Comment: .right.menu{position: relative;}

.right.menu.search-on {
    padding-right: 50px;
}

Comment: If you need to set     margin-left: 0px !important; instead of the framework's     margin-left: auto!important; then I can help.
But in your fiddle, that still doesn't seem to be a solution.